# How do I link individual TableView cell to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am making this notes taking app and I get the user to enter the Title and the notes regarding the same. I then print the title of notes in a TableView cell then I have linked the cell to another ViewController which shows notes related to the specific Title. I have successfully created a segue for me to go to another VC but how do I print different notes for each title in a TextView. The code I wrote appends my text and gives the same notes TextView in all case.

This is the **VC** code where I have the notesField and the title field

```
@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
{

        list.append(textField.text!)
        list2.append(notesField.text!)

}
```

Then I print this notes Field into the new VC by

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    notesShow.text = list2.joined(separator: "\n")

}
```

what I get is same textView in all the Titles and the text appends. **How do I get a separate notes for each Title ?**

Answer (score 0):

When you are navigating to another VC after clicking on perticular `TableViewCell` .
Do this:

In your VC, declare a dictionary.

```
var notesDictionary: [String: Any]?
```

And in your `didSelectRow` method before navigating,

```
obj.notesDictionary = self.yourCurrentDictionary
self.navigationController(push...obj)
```

Now. You can access notesDictionary in your VC's viewDidLoad to get values.

Comment: it says "unresolved identifier obj" though I had "performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: self)" in my didSelectRow.

Comment: By obj I meant your object. Use whatever object you've created of your VC.